# How to Check with jQuery if Image URL is Empty and Do something?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am loading XML feed from another site with PHP. My output in HTML is like this:

```
<div class="sponsored">
<div class='box'><img src='http:///xxx.jpg'><a href='xxx'>Title</a></div> 
<div class='box'><img src='http:///xxx.jpg'><a href='xxx'>Title</a></div>
<div class='box'><img src='http:///xxx.jpg'><a href='xxx/'>Title</a></div>
<div class='box'><img src=''><a href='xxx'>Title</a></div>   
</div>
```

The last part has no src url, meaning the feed didn't provide any image. I would like to check this HTML output with jquery to check if there's no src url. and if so, then put defauly image for better formatting.

I saw jquery scripts that check for images within div. But is there a way to check if images src is empty or not?

================

UPDATE:

Ok, I'm not sure why it didn't work before. Finally the code below works on my end:

```
$(".sponsored > .box > img[src='']").attr("src","default.png");
```

Thank You All for Answers!! Here's final working code for future noobs like me :)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sponsored > .box > img[src='']").attr("src","image.jpg");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `attribute equals` selector,

```
$(".sponsored > .box > img[src='']").attr("src","default.png");
```

Comment: strange, it doesn't add the default.png to the code

Comment: @reizer Have a look at it. https://jsfiddle.net/t5j6gxdk/ It should work. If not can you reproduce the same in a new fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use like that, this example will give you `3 not empty` records and `1 empty` record, you can check the result in browser console:

```js
$('.box img').each(function(index,val){
    if($(this).attr('src') == ''){
      console.log('empty');
    }
    else{
     console.log('not empty');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sponsored">
<div class='box'><img src='http:///xxx.jpg'><a href='xxx'>Title</a></div> 
<div class='box'><img src='http:///xxx.jpg'><a href='xxx'>Title</a></div>
<div class='box'><img src='http:///xxx.jpg'><a href='xxx/'>Title</a></div>
<div class='box'><img src=''><a href='xxx'>Title</a></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sponsored .box img").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('src') == ''){
            $(this).attr('src') = 'default.png';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanx, but i can't get it to work for some reason... it's not adding anything to the url attribute for the empty image

Comment: use $(this).attr('src','default.png');

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.sponsored .box img').each(function () {
    if (this.src!== undefined && this.src!='') {
        console.log("Exists");
    }else
    {
        console.log("Not Exists");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.box img').each(function(){
if($(this).attr('src') == ''){
  //do something
}
else{
  //do something
}
});
```